# How can i select blank and cell while doing loop in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste "Thomos" in column F six times where cell value in column F is blank and cell value in column J is non-blank.

After that I want to paste "jerry" in column F six times where cell value in column K is non-blank and cell value in column F is blank.

When I run the code jerry is pasted in the cells in column F where Thomos is present.

```vba
Sub populate()

Dim iVal As Integer
Dim Val As Integer
For Each Cel In Range("J2:J100")
    For Each blk In Range("F2:F100")
        If Cel.value <> "" And blk.value = "" Then
            Cel.Offset(0, -4).value = "Thomos"
        Else
        End If
        iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F100"), "Thomos")
        If iVal = 6 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

For Each Rng In Range("K2:K100")
    For Each blk2 In Range("F2:F100")
        If Rng.value <> "" And blk2.value = "" Then
            Rng.Offset(0, -5).value = "jerry"
        Else
        End If
        Val = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F100"), "jerry")
        If Val = 6 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: "Thomos" in column f 6 times in the same cell? In adjacent rows within the same column?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all cells in `F` everytime you go through one cell in `J` and `K`. So if (for example) `Cel` is not `""` for cell `K4` and `blk2` is `""` for cell `F9`, you have satisfied your conditions and `K4.Offset(0,-5)` will be assigned a value of `Jerry` whether of not *it* is blank. You only need one for:

```
iVal = 0
For Each Cel In Range("F2:F100")
    If Cel.value = "" And Cell.Offset(0,4).value <> "" Then
        Cel.value = "Thomos"
        iVal = iVal + 1
    End If
    If iVal = 6 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

ival = 0
For Each Cel In Range("F2:F100")
    If Cel.value = "" And Cell.Offset(0,5).value <> "" Then
        Cel.value = "Jerry"
        iVal = iVal + 1
    End If
    If iVal = 6 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

An alternative:

```
iVal1 = 0
iVal2 = 0
For Each Cel In Range("F2:F100")
    If Cel.value = "" And Cell.Offset(0,4).value <> "" and iVal1 <6 Then
        Cel.value = "Thomos"
        iVal1 = iVal1 + 1
    End If
    If Cel.value = "" And Cell.Offset(0,5).value <> "" and iVal2 <6 Then
        Cel.value = "Jerry"
        iVal2 = iVal2 + 1
    End If
    If iVal1 = 6 and iVal2 = 6 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. Below is the code i have written with the help of you.

```html
Sub populate()

Dim iVal As Integer
Dim iVal2 As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F100"), Range("x2"))
iVal2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F100"), Range("x3"))
ival3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F100"), Range("x4"))
iVal1 = 0
iVal2 = 0
ival3 = 0
For Each Cel In Range("F2:F100")
    If Cel.value = "" And Cel.Offset(0, 4).value <> "" And iVal < Range("y2") Then
        Cel.value = Range("x2")
        iVal = iVal + 1
    End If
    If Cel.value = "" And Cel.Offset(0, 5).value <> "" And iVal2 < Range("y3") Then
        Cel.value = Range("x3")
        iVal2 = iVal2 + 1
    End If
        If Cel.value = "" And Cel.Offset(0, 6).value <> "" And ival3 < Range("y4") Then
        Cel.value = Range("x4")
        ival3 = ival3 + 1
    End If
    If iVal1 = Range("y2") And iVal2 = Range("y3") And ival3 = Range("y4") Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```